# 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python

I'm doing the merge sort in python but I have a problem. When I try to split data by delimiter (one number per line which return a list of string) I cannot convert it in integers. Can you help me understanding the problem. 
I try to convert data csv file from horizontal data format to vertical data from to implement eclat algorithm. can anybody help me?

```
from sys import argv
import sys
from itertools import chain, combinations
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(r'2010.csv',engine='python', header=None)

def Read_Data(filename):
    data = {}
    trans = 0

    for row in filename:
        trans += 1
        for item in row.split(','):
            if item not in data:
                data[item] = set()
            data[item].add(trans)

    return data

item = Read_Data(data)
```

Comment: Could you reformat this so the code is all readable, and ensure you've included all relevant code. Thanks!

Comment: put `print (row, type(row))` after `for row in filename:` and you will solve the mystery

Comment: @NineBerry I don't think so, `filename` is just a really bad variable name, look at the call `Read_Data(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a [type()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) check before your second loop to make sure you're on'y splitting on a `str`. Also you can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead of using `trans` variable. Also a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would be better than having to make a set for every item. It will do that for you automatically.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def Read_Data(filename):
    data = defaultdict(set)

    for trans, row in enumerate(filename):
        if isinstance(row, str):
            for item in row.split(','):
                data[item].add(trans)
        else:
            #something to this effect
            data['numbers'].add(trans)

    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) states:

> **Returns**: `DataFrame` or `TextParser`

So when you try:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'2010.csv',engine='python', header=None)
item = Read_Data(data)
```

Your inner loop does not iterates on `str`-ings:

```
for row in filename: # filename is DataFrame or TextParser
    for item in row.split(','):  ## it's not a string. You can't split it
```

So you are incorrect in your expectation of existence of method `split`